# Is this sentence correct: "She didn't have any book with her."

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct? "She didn't have any book with her."

Comment: I might say, "She didn't have any *books* with her."

Comment: What do you think might be wrong with it - and what is the context? [Please, don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site. : Proofreading ("are there any mistakes?"), unless the source of concern is clearly specified](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @KaiserOctavius Why please? Only plural will work?

Comment: Whoa @TrevorD & generous up voters to the comment: the OP is only 1-rep old, so hold your horses for now. There will be a way to migrate questions over to ELL, now or soon enough.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better on ELL

Answer (score 3):

It’s grammatical and used, in the words of the Oxford English Dictionary’s definition 1b, to mean ‘None at all; none of any kind, quantity, or number, even the minutest; not even one’.

It needs to be used in this way with care, as it will not be appropriate in all contexts.